# searchkick find in location radius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I'm wondering what the best way would be to tackle this. I have a search function which looks like this:

```
  def search
    search_options = {
      misspellings: { edit_distance: 2 },
      fields: [:eventname, :date],
      order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc },
      match: :word_start,
      suggest: true,
      page: params[:page],
      per_page: 20
    }
    if params[:date_from].present?
      datefrom = params[:date_from].to_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      dateto = params[:date_to].to_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      search_options[:where] =  { date: {gte: datefrom, lte: dateto} }
    end

    @events = Event.search params[:search], search_options
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    else
      @popevents = Event.limit(3).order('RANDOM()')
      render 'events/noresults'
    end
  end
```

Now what i'm wanting to do is add a search functionality that would allow people to search for events within 50 miles of their postcode that they enter.

I have a postcode field in my events table with the postcode of all the events locations.

What would be the best way to do this? (simple if possible kinda like a hold your hand guide would be amazing!!)

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder). There's no support on the database or in Rails for native postcode search, but you can use a geocoding service to get the latitude and longitude for each address that you store. This involves adding these columns to your database.

`geocode` has good documentation, and it will help you both with geocoding (getting the lat/lng) and searching by distance (although you can also use `searchkick` for the latter)